# Laptop doesn't see my wireless network

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

My hp probook 4710s laptop sees any other wireless network but mine. I changed the mode to Mixed(802.11b+802.11g+802.11n), I changed the channel from auto to 1, and then any other channel and still, my laptop can't see the network.

Comment: Can you add it manually in Windows and connect to it ? Make sure that Broadcasting option is enabled in the router configuration.

Comment: You can see here the router settings https://www.dropbox.com/s/lcj541pfvf0fz03/wifi.png